# QGIS 3.4 $area not equal for same shape

Tags: qgis, area, grids-graticules

First, I created a regular grid of the size 1km^2 (epsg: 2056). Then I calculated the area of of this grid using different GIS:

Python: arcpy

> area_arc

```
# Python Setup
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Data_in
poly = "C:/Hexbins.shp"

# Area Caculation
arcpy.AddField_management(poly,'area_arc','DOUBLE')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(poly,'area_arc','!shape.area!','PYTHON')
#arcpy.CalculateGeometryAttributes_management(poly,["area_arcpy", "AREA"],'Meters')
```

R sf

> area_sf

```
Hexbins<- read_sf("LC:/Hexbins.shp")

Hexbins<-Hexbins %>% 
mutate(
area_sf= as.vector(st_area(.))
)
```

QGIS

> area_q

```
Field calculator: 
Input: poly
- output field name: area_q
Output field type: Decimal number (real)
Outpu field length: 10
Precision: 3
Expression: $area
```

> area_q2

```
Field calculator: 
Input: poly
- output field name: area_q
Output field type: Whole number
Outpu field length: 10
Precision: 3
Expression: $area
```

The libraries Python arcpy and R sf lead to the expected result of 1km^2. The result I obtained using qgis is somewhat astonishing:

The libraries Python arcpy and R sf lead to the expected result of 1km^2. The result I obtained using QGIS $area is somewhat astonishing:

[image]

Is there an explanation for this randomness?

Answer (score 4):

This is because [EPSG:2056](http://epsg.io/2056) is an [Oblique Mercator projection](http://www.georeference.org/doc/oblique_mercator.htm) that is "An oblique cylindrical projection that is conformal but not equal area". So it doesn't preserve area (as you are seeing).

Comment: Interesting, but why do R sf and Python arcpy lead to the result I expected? I used the same CRS for all area calculations.

Comment: rounding error?

Comment: R sf and Python arcpy lead to exactly 1'000'000 m^2 = 1km^2. It seems to me that QGIS calculates the area differently than R sf and Python arcpy. I do not see, where the rounding errors could happen.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/258027/why-the-outcome-of-area-geometry-is-different-from-area-saga-shape-indices-t